# Storing multiple integers in a Berkeley DB

Tags: key, berkeley-db

I need to store an ordered list of 32 bit integers for each key in a Berkeley DB (keys are also 32 bit integers).

Should I use multiple-keys feature or just store them as a string of bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll drive yourself crazy with the multiple keys feature.  Store it in a single record.